# Can $\mathbb A=\{f(x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ be shortened as $\mathbb A=f(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

> Can $\mathbb A=\{f(x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ be shortened as $\mathbb A=f(\mathbb R)$?

I saw this notation in the [IMO olympiad training materials](http://imomath.com/index.php?options=257&lmm=0) (the solution to the Problem 16 (IMO 1999 Problem 6) [here](http://imomath.com/index.php?options=341&lmm=0)).

Because the source seems reliable, I believe the notation is correct, but can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes, though in the specific context of set theory (where elements of sets may be sets themselves, and sometimes a set $a$ is both an element and a subset of another set $b$), this may lead to ambiguity, so some authors prefer either using square brackets, as in $f[\mathbb R]$, or even $f``\mathbb R$.

Comment: This notation is often used in point set topology, esp. with relations that need not be functions, as for example talking about $f^{-1}(\mathscr{O})$ for an open set $\mathscr{O}$ as the "pre-image" of that set.